# React Router v6.4.1 createBrowserRouter not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm creating an app with react v18 & react-router-dom v6.4.1 where I'm using the `createBrowserRouter` function as they show in the docs (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#adding-a-router). However, it's not working at all even when just configuring a simple root route which returns a simple `div` with "Hello World!" in it.

Here is the code I use & the error I get. Is there something I'm missing?

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <div>Hello World!</div>
  }
])

export default router
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried this in my PC

You should declare this in a .tsx file.

It doesn't work in a .ts file.

I hope this works for you

Comment: Ok wow, completely looked over that... Thanks for fixing my (stupid) mistake!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have spent more than a day to figure this out.